# Use buttons in game-style scenario

Tags: android

I have a 5 linear layouts, each containing 10 buttons, which gives rise to a 5 by 10 array of buttons. I would like the user to select 5 buttons, and each button contains a certain point value. On the next page, I would like the sum of the point values of these 5 buttons to appear in a textview.

Here is what I have tried so far, using a small sample of my code.

**On the xml file:** (this is a 2 by 3 sample)

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button11"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="50" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button12"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="50" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button13"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="75" />

    </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button21"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="00" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button22"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="25" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button23"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="75" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

I am not sure what to do on the java file, but I was considering giving each `button id` a value (which is currently represented by the name of the button) and adding up all the values, which will then be displayed on the next page.

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert the text on the button to an integer:

```
int value = 0;
try {
    value = Integer.parseInt(button.getText().toString());
} 
catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Say that xml file is called activity_main.xml. You need to have an Activity class, let's call it MainActivity.java

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private totalVal = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button button12 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button12);
        button12.setOnClickListener(this);

        // ... Do the same for the rest of the buttons

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch(v.getId(){
            case R.id.button12: 
                int textVal = Integer.parseInt(v.getText().toString());
                totalVal = totalVal + textVal;
                // do whatever else you want to when the button is clicked
                break;
            // ... Do the same for the rest of the buttons
    }
```

You would also need a button that says you are done, and implement it in a similar way